# Using select, option value inside the actionlink

Tags: c#, parameters, html.actionlink

```
if (@ViewBag.Title == "Title")
{

@ViewBag.Title
<div class="btnNEW" hidden id="fqXLS">
<select id = "fqcXLS">
<option id ="fqcXLSa">A</option>
<option id ="fqcXLSb">B</option>
<option id ="fqcXLSc">C</option>
<option id ="fqcXLSd">D</option>
</select>

@Html.ActionLink("Export To Excel", "ExportToExcel", "EEC", new { option = ??? }, new { @class = "cancel" })
</div>
}
```

I was able to make it work just by doing      new{option="A"}    but this will only send "A"

How can I use the selected value?

Comment: Looks like none of your `<option>` tags have their `value` attribute populated, [see the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option). Also it depends how you want to use the selected value? If in Javascript then see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1085810/3338349

Comment: <option id ="fqcXLSa" value = "A">A</option>
<option id ="fqcXLSb" value = "A">B</option>
<option id ="fqcXLSc" value = "A">C</option>
<option id ="fqcXLSd" value = "A">D</option>

So, after setting my options with values, how can I pass it from the actionlink?

option = document.getElementById("fqxXLS").value ? or something like this?

Comment: I've also tried

@Html.ActionLink("Export To Excel", "ExportToExcel", "EEC", new { option= "getCategory();" }, new { @class = "cancel" })

creating a function to return the value of the ID, then call that function inside the actionlink. Doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ActionLink is created when the page is first rendered.  It is not updated when the user selects from the dropdownlist (it will have the same initial value).  Therefore, you will need to update the anchor href value using javascript or jquery.

There are many ways to achieve this, below is an unobtrusive way:

1) Give the ActionLink an ID:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Export To Excel", 
                 "ExportToExcel", 
                 "EEC", 
                  null, 
                  new { @id = "lnkCancel", @class = "cancel" })
```

2) Add event listener for the onchange event of the dropdown list (this should be called once the document is ready/loaded):

```
// get the dropdownlist
var ddl = document.getElementById('fqcXLS');

// add event listener for 'onchange'
ddl.addEventListener('change', function () {
    var url = '@Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "EEC")';           // base url
    var link = document.getElementById('lnkCancel');           // get link to update 
    var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;  // get selected value
    link.href = url + '?option=' + selectedValue;              // update link href
});
```

This will update the anchor href attribute when the select list is changed.

```js
var ddl = document.getElementById('mySelect');

ddl.addEventListener('change', function () {

  var url = 'somesite/myaction';           // base url
  var link = document.getElementById('lnkCancel');           // get link to update 
  var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;  // get selected value
  link.href = url + '?option=' + selectedValue;              // update link href
  
  link.innerText = link.href;  // dont include this, this just shows the url text
});
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" >
    <option value="A" selected>A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
 </select>
  
  <a href="somesite/myaction" id="lnkCancel" >Select item in dropdown</a>
```

Comment: #1 giving the actionlink an id
```
=> @Html.ActionLink("Export To Excel", "ExportToExcel", "EEC", new { @id = "fqcXLS" }, new { @class = "cancel" })
```
like this?

Comment: Does it not work the way I wrote it? @locomotive The `@id` should be set under HtmlAttributes where the `@class` tag is set.

Comment: You could also just replace the `Html.ActionLink` with a regular anchor tag with id `<a id="myId">`.

Comment: The way you wrote? I don't know what lnkCancel is for

Comment: You need to alter the URL of the link when the select list is changed.  One way to do this is to give the link (ActionLink) an ID so you can change the value.  `lnkCancel` was just the name I gave it, you can name it anything.  You need to use javascsript or jquery to do what you want it to, its not possible without. @locomotive

Comment: So after editing your #1 and #2, how can I get the value from my function?

 public ActionResult ExportToExcel(String ???)

Comment: I'm trying to send a selected value as the parameter attribute to the function.
It works when I do    new { name = "x"}  but this will send only specific value "x".

Comment: Yes, I know what you're trying to do.  What is the problem?  Does my code update the URL when the select list changes? You can check by hovering the mouse over the URL and inspecting the value.  Does your project have jquery because a jquery solution would be simpler. @locomotive

Comment: I really can't understand how the actionlink works.
In my method, what do I need to have in the parameter to get the value?
Am I putting the #2 in the script function?

Comment: I've tried doing public ActionResult ExportToExcel(String lnkCancel) and it give null for lnkCancel

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("Export To Excel", "ExportToExcel", "EEC", new { category = "????" }, new { @class = "cancel" })
Instead of ????, I need to pass the selected value so that I can use it in the method public ActionResult ExportToExcel(String category) {...} like this

Comment: conclusion: your way will give something like this <a class="cancel" href="/YourController/YourAction" id="lnkCancel"> but I do not know how to use this in the method parameter to get the value.
I need something like <a class="cancel" href="/YourController/YourAction?category=A"> so that I can use category parameter in my method to use the value.

Comment: @locomotive Yes, exactly.  That's what the javascript code does... it adds `?option=A` to the link when A is selected in the list.  Put it in `<script>` tags at the bottom of the page. Change `option` to `category` if that's the variable you're using... your question uses `option` not `category`. What is the variable in the controller?  I used an event listener so you don;t need to put it in a function. Another way would be to put it in a function and use `onchange` in the select list.

Comment: `lnkCancel` has nothing to do with the controller... it's just an html ID for the anchor `<a>` link.

Comment: ok, I think I understood what you were trying to say.
So I did put #2 in a script at the end of the page, and used #1 actionlink.
Then i used parameter option in my method, it's saying null.

Comment: @locomotive I'm sorry, there was a couple of errors in my javascript.  This line: `ddl.addEventListener('change', function () {` and this line `var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;` have been corrected. Hope this works for you now.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I got it now.
Only other problem I'm having now is when I try to use the value from the parameter, it causes an issue.
...**method (string option){do something with option} = problem**...
...**method (string option){option = "value" then do something} = no problem**...
Basically, I can see the value coming over as string, but it causes problems making excel file, which works fine when I just give a string value.

Comment: @locomotive I'm glad the solution worked for you! I think it would be best to ask another question. I'm not sure what you mean, ... it would be easier to understand if you posted another question with an example of what the problem is :)